# CartThrob CT Admin statuses all mixed up

Tags: cartthrob, status

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction for an issue I'm having with CartThrob Order Channel statuses being all mixed up.

Basically, the orders channel has the statuses of several other channels being displayed. So there are the 7 or so payment related / shipped statuses that should be there, and an extra 10 from other status groups.

**For instance:**

```
Open
Printed
Packaged
Shipped
Payment Processing
Payment Refunded
Featured < Shouldn't be here
Draft < Shouldn't be here
Featured Home Page < Shouldn't be here
Etc. Etc. + 10 more < Shouldn't be here
Closed
```

Also, if I go to Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > Edit Group Assignments and select, "None", only the Order Statuses stop displaying. All the other group statuses continue to display in CT Admin, Order Manager and when editing in publish view.

Perhaps someone here knows there way around the Cartthrob / EE database tables, so I can load up phpMyAdmin and work it out manually?

Thank you for any assistance,

Comment: The EE statusses are easy to find in exp_status and exp_status_group.  So maybe look there first.  exp_cartthrob_status holds the actual statusses for orders - but these reflect the CT payment statusses not the order statusses as such.  Not an answer but might get you started looking in the right places maybe.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I've looked through exp_status and exp_status_group but I'm still at square one with it. Hoping maybe the cartthrob guys will see this, or someone that may have seen something similar that can suggest a fix. I'm working with an admin person that needs things to be, well, really simple. lol.